# ssh and execute several commands as another user through a heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a script that I need to execute through ssh as another use, is there a way to pass whole script like this:

```
ssh -t user@server.com sudo -u user2 sh -c << EOF
 cd /home
 ls
 dir=$(pwd)
 echo "$dir"
 echo "hello"
 ....
EOF
```

Returns: ***sh: -c: option requires an argument***

**ssh'ing** and **sudo'ing** separately is not an option and putting .sh file directly on the machine is not possible.

Comment: not a duplicate, this one requires to ssh as another user and I need to pass whole script without expects

Comment: I added another duplicate which may perhaps explain your situation better.

Comment: The issue here was with `sh -c` rather than the heredoc.  So, it is not exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sh -c` requires a command string as the argument.  Since you are reading the commands from standard input (through heredoc), you need to use `sh -s` option:

```
ssh -t user@server.com sudo -u user2 sh -s << 'EOF'
 cd /home
 ls
 dir=$(pwd)
 echo "$dir"
 echo "hello"
 ...
EOF
```

From `man sh`:

> -c
>
> string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string,  they  are  assigned  to  the  positional parameters, starting with $0.
>
> -s
>
> If  the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input.  This option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.

Need to quote the heredoc marker to prevent the parent shell from interpreting the content.

Comment: ok this is exactly what I needed, thanks a bunch